# ImportError: No module named asn1crypto.algos

Tags: python, ssh, remote-access

I am trying to connect to a remote machine through ssh and I try to use paramiko. and i used below mention code followed by some custom python code. .

```
import paramiko

def start_connection():
    u_name = 'root'
    pswd = ''
    port = 22
    r_ip = '198.x.x.x'
    sec_key = '/mycert.ppk'

    myconn = paramiko.SSHClient()
    myconn.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
    my_rsa_key = paramiko.RSAKey.from_private_key_file(sec_key)

    session = myconn.connect(r_ip, username =u_name, password=pswd, port=port,pkey=my_rsa_key)
...
...

follow python code to perform some actions on remote machine.
```

but i got few other errors and i installed those modules, but now i am getting this weird error.

```
ImportError: No module named asn1crypto.algos
```

Can someone help me in this regard or suggest me an alternative with example to ssh a remote machine. I enter into one machine through ssh and there I want to run python script which check modification time of files on another remote machine. I am trying to add this ssh user and password in this same python script. 
I would be grateful for any tip or help

Answer (score 3):

I ran into this issue when installing with Conda.  Try upgrading the paramiko package with pip:

```
    pip install --upgrade paramiko
```